# Nginx redirrect http to https

Tags: redirect, nginx

I need to redirect all the http requests to https  in nginx and also to use some self-generated SSL certificate (using opensssl), but something is wrong with my configuration:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name x.x.x.x;

  # 301 = permanent redirect, 302 = temporary redirect
  #return 301  https://x.x.x.x;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name x.x.x.x;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key; 
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details of the error? Is that the default site or is it a custom site configuration file? If the latter, do you still have enabled the default site?

Comment: Location was missing.